# Combining Code in Main Activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I have used the template for creating tabs and swipe procedurals in android but have now not been able to create a list within the main activity. How can I combine the following two sections of code?

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" />


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

has to go on top of everything. The `ViewPager` shouldn't be the root element of your layout. I suggest setting `LinearLayout` as the root element of your main layout and set the `ViewPager` inside as a child.

I guess [this tutorial](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/view-pager-example-in-android-development/) might be helpful. It employs Android's [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Comment: I would vote you up but my reputation won't let me. Thanks though!